# What is the problem with 'react-native-elements'?

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

When I try to use 'react-native-elements' package in my code, I face this error :

> bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome` from `node_modules\react-native-elements\src\social\SocialIcon.js`: react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome could not be found within the project.

I have done many things to fix it. I installed the 'react-native-vector-icons' again, I used 'rm ./node_modules/react-native/local-cli/core/fixtures/files/package.json' but non of them worked. what should I do to overcome this problem? I really appreciate your help guys.

Comment: i was facing the same weird problems. its better i got rid of vector icons and used scalable images for those icons which dont have such hassles

Answer (score 7, accepted):

make sure that you've installed the package with 
**npm install react-native-vector-icons**  and link it through

**react-native link react-native-vector-icons**

then for ios you need to install pod (goto your project ios folder on terminal and enter command **pod install**)

and then reset packager cache with react-native start --reset-cache

Comment: If an answer was helpful and solved your problem, i would suggest to mark it as accepted and upvote it ^^

Answer (score 0):

if you are using react version <0.60 use `react-native link react-native-vector-icons` and do the steps [link](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#option-manually) and if react version > 0.60 then `cd ios && pod install && cd ..` and try again if its not work delete the build folder and rebuild again.